# Python 3.7.3 ./configure --with-openssl could not find ssl.h

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, openssl

I've downloaded Python 3.7.3 source code and want to make and install it with openssl support.

From ./configure --help found that new option --with-openssl should point to folder that openssl-devel is installed.

I've installed openssl-devel.x86_64 for my Centos before and when make command `ls /usr/include/openssl |grep ssl` , I find ssl.h but when pass with argument to  `./configure --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl/` or  `./configure --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl` ,

it says checking for `openssl/ssl.h in /usr/include/openssl/... n`o

Comment: It's just `--with-openssl=/usr`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Thanks man, it solved my problem, is there any way to debug and tracing such configure scripts in these situations that make me confused?

Comment: Well, a file called `compile.log` is written during `./configure, it often contains useful information.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond at the end find that another error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Comment: While compiling, create log-files, eg: `make all 2>&1 | tee log.make.all` and `make install 2>&1 | tee log.make.install`. Then check the log-files for error messages related to ctypes. NB: When installed, don't forget to call `ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep python`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I've finally find _ctypes error in python 3.7.3 bugs in here: https://bugs.python.org/issue31652 and here https://bugs.python.org/msg321740 for centos

Comment: You might want to install libffi: `yum install -y libffi libffi-devel` (as root)